# Add/Remove current_page_parent class

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus, navigation

I created some custom post types and custom taxonomies, if I'm on an archive page of the custom taxonomy, the *Blog* menu item is highlighted due to the `current_page_parent` class.
Well this is obviously false and I want to remove the class, but I also want to add it to another menu item.

How can I add and remove the `current_page_parent` class dynamically for all my custom taxonomies?

I'm currently removing the class with

```
function wpdev_nav_classes( $classes ) {
  if( is_archive() ){
    $classes = array_diff( $classes, array( 'current_page_parent' ) );
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpdev_nav_classes', 10, 2 );
```

but I have no clue on how to add it to an other menu item, let's call the item *Example*.

Comment: The 2nd argument passed to the `nav_menu_css_class` filter is the menu item, you can check the title, ID, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Replace `news` with your custom post type and `menu-item-000` with the menu item you want to highlight.

```
function wpdev_nav_classes($classes) {
    // Remove "current_page_parent" class
    $classes = array_diff( $classes, array( 'current_page_parent' ) );

    // If this is the "news" custom post type, highlight the correct menu item
    if ( in_array('menu-item-000', $classes) && get_post_type() === 'news' ) {
        $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'wpdev_nav_classes');
```

If you have more than one post type, it would be better to use a switch statement. Let me know if that's the case, and I'll update the code.

Comment: This is helpful for me. Would this be the most satisfactory way of doing this?